# How can I imitate this modal effect in a Wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I want to imitate the effect on http://www.homeloanrepublic.com.au/ such that when you click on the mail icon on their navigation bar, it will display an existing section in the homepage on a modal form.

How can I do this (preferably with no plugins, but plugin suggestions are welcome too)?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to help a beginner out by at least stating your reason when downvoting my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be relatively simple to achieve using jQuery show/hide.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_show

Apply show when someone clicks the email icon and hide when someone clicks close. It's then just a case of using CSS and position:fixed; for the div.